# Multi selection problem on Swing JCheckbox

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, selection

I have a list of checkboxes, but I can not make multi selection from this list, it disables the previous selection when I check a new box. how can I change my code? or if it looks ok and by accident I do something wrong somewhere else in my code.

```
public JPanel createMultiMenu(ArrayList<String> domainItems) {

    checkBoxMenuPanel = new JPanel();
    checkBoxMenuPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    for (String item : domainItems) {
        JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox(item);
        group.add(checkBox);
        checkBoxMenuPanel.add(checkBox,gbc);        
    }
    return checkBoxMenuPanel;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using ButtonGroup, which treats objects placed in it as radiobuttons (you can only select one at a time).

Instead try just adding them to the JPanel.

```
public JPanel createMultiMenu(ArrayList<String> domainItems) {

    checkBoxMenuPanel = new JPanel();
    checkBoxMenuPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;


    for (String item : domainItems) {
        JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox(item);
        checkBoxMenuPanel.add(checkBox, gbc);        
    }
    return checkBoxMenuPanel;
}
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 4):

That is the way a ButtonGroup works, you can select any button in the group but only 1 can be selected at a time. Also generally a JRadioButton is used for this.

If you want to be able to select multiple checkboxes, then don't use a ButtonGroup.

Comment: ok and what should I use instead? that code works good in terms of alignment issues. I want to select multiple values not only one

Comment: @XDeveloper.  Take out the line that says `group.add(checkBox)`.  Can you can check multiple boxes now?

Answer (score 2):

May be you need JRadioButtons? Use ButtonGroup and add all radiobuttons in the group. After that if you select any of them previously selected looses the selected state.

Comment: sorry,  I can NOT make multi selection from this list,